# Raspberry Pi Wifi Pineapple/Access Point, Wifi honey pot setup error!

Tags: wifi, apache-httpd, packages

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3s9KYCU3tE

I have been following this tutorial for a while and I have come across a problem that will not let me finish the setup by running:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

What I am trying to do is use my Raspberry Pi as a WiFi pineapple! This tutorial has gone great so far, but when I tried to run this, it gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,750 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,241 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 apache2-bin apache2-utils apache2-data apache2 ssl-cert
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libapr1 armhf 1.5.1-3
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1 armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libaprutil1-ldap armhf 1.5.4-1
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua5.1-0 armhf 5.1.5-7.1
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-bin armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-utils armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2-data all 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main apache2 armhf 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
404  Not Found
 Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main ssl-cert all     1.0.35
404  Not Found
 E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.5.1-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

 E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua5.1/liblua5.1-0_5.1.5-7.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.0.35_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Please Help, Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the directory you are trying to access does not exist:
[image]

Try running `sudo apt-get update` first, this will update your source list to the current directory structure.

Comment: i have done that and it gives me a similar error.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
(theres more error text but the comment won't fit it.)

Comment: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: then i say ok i'll try the apache again now but it doesn't work still! please help :(

Comment: Hello i need help with this??

Comment: This is weird. The files are there, your links are good. Try `ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org`, make sure it's not a networking issue. The server does seem slow though, maybe it's just timing out and apt-get assumes the file is not there.

Comment: Actually, it may be related to AWS's recent performance issues. --> https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/

Comment: That works but it still doesn't run without giving the error.

Comment: how do i fix it??

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org
PING mirrordirector.raspbian.org (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=3.59 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=4.38 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=3.51 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=3.26 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=3.68 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=3.95 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl

Comment: See it works, but doesn't help, does this give you any important info to help me??

Comment: Try installing something else. Try `sudo apt-get install htop`, it's a simple task manager, you can always remove it after.

Comment: didn't work:( heres the error

Comment: Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main htop armhf 1.0.3-1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/h/htop/htop_1.0.3-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: same error i got before. :(

Answer (score 0):

We've narrowed it down to the likely cause:

- your `apt-get` is messed up, most likely because your SD card is messed up.

This can happen for a number of reasons, the most common are:

- the SD card got corrupted through pulling the plug on the Pi without issuing a software shutdown first
- the SD card wasn't flashed properly to begin with

I'm willing to bet this is a new Pi with a newly flashed SD card and that you haven't installed any packages with it prior to this. Reflash your SD card, and try this project again.

Comment: oh yes that is true it is new ok i will do that,but will that delete any data?

Comment: thank you! i will try this and hope it works, it may not and if it doesn't i will come back and tell you! thank you

Comment: Yes, you will lose all your data. Sometimes, the data doesn't get written properly during the flash process, so you DO want to lose all your data. :)

Comment: ok i will do that if it doesn't work i'll come back.

Comment: i tried and i got a error in disk utility!

Comment: How are you flashing the card? On Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Mac os X disk utility.

Comment: 2 things: 1) make sure you're not using a "built-in" card reader, they are not dependable. Get a $5 USB card reader and 2) follow these instruction https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md

Comment: ok i re-downloaded the os and now it says the ssh is refused in terminal. do i have to boot it up once before being able to ssh into it?? why does it say connection refused. I think i actually by accidentally sshed into someone else's pi lol! becuase to password wasn't raspberry or pi. but anyway do i have to do something to ssh into it.

Comment: Since November 2016, SSH is disabled by default. See here on how to enable it --> https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: i enabled it and now when ssh it says someone might be spying on me a (man in the middle attack)

Comment: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:Osp6CcOmqP0KzgA+AZ+KsTvcPNm10rTmYLvSmHJldIw.
Please contact your system administrator.

Comment: when i try to ssh into in it, in terminal that is what it says what should i do?!??

Comment: Add correct host key in /Users/sergei/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/sergei/.ssh/known_hosts:1
ECDSA host key for 192.168.2.2 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
Sergeis-Mac:~ sergei$

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update`.
It happened once with me. It seemed to have outdated repository addresses. Running the command above solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not able to download anything is because you set your dnsmasq address, interface, and dhcp-range to point to a static IP. Comment those lines out and reboot. You may also need to restore the interface changes you made under `/etc/network/interfaces`.

The tutorial shows you how to setup an access point, but doesn't include how to share your internet from the host machine/router.